# How to pick current system date from date picker using Katalon recorder?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-ide, katalon

I am unable to add a calendar date picker using Katalon recorder. What value should be given to pick current system date?

```
Command: Sendkeys, 
Target: id of the element 
value: ? (what is the value?)
```

Comment: hello can please add code here... so that we can know what does actual problem

Comment: 1.) //div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/a  and //td[6]/a both these are highlighting tomorrows date in date picker however I want the ide script to pick current  system date every time I pick required date.